# How to deepcopy LpVariables

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I need to deepcopy a `LpProblem`, but `LpVariables` of problem copies by reference when i use `LpProblem.deepcopy()` method. In this situation if i change the upper bound of one of variables of the copy problem, this change affect the original problem variables.

Consider following situation:

```
    branch1 = currentProblem.deepcopy()
    v = ... # some variable of branch1
    v.upBound = 10
```

in this case, upper bound of a variable in `currentProblem` also changes to 10.

How can i deep copy a `LpProblem` that deep copies all of its elements? (including `LpVariables`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no solution for this. So i wrote two functions to save and restore values of `LpVariables`. It helps me for this situation.

```
def saveVarsAsDict(lpProblem):
    varsNameValue = {}
    for v in lpProblem._variables:
        if v.varValue != 0:
            varsNameValue[v.name] = v.varValue
    return varsNameValue


def restoreVarsValues(lpProblem, varsNameValue):
    for v in lpProblem._variables:
        if v.name in varsNameValue:
            v.varValue = varsNameValue[v.name]
        else:
            v.varValue = 0
```